# NHibernate 3.3.3 Medium Trust simple site not working out of the box

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, dependency-injection

I have created a simple bare web site with NHibernate running under Medium Trust and despite all the research I have done saying it should work I can not get the simplest of examples working. Here are my steps

1. Create new web site in VS2012 targeting .Net 4.0.
2. Add FluentNHibernate via NuGet. Also add NHibernate.DependencyInjection package. Also installs NHibernate 3.3.3.
3. Configure web.config to run in Medium Trust.
4. Create simple session factory. Connect to a MSSQL database. Use `CurrentSessionContext(typeof(ManagedWebSessionContext).FullName)`

At this point, everyone seems to suggest all you have to do in Application_Start is call

`NHibernate.DependencyInjection.Initializer.RegisterBytecodeProvider();`

But when I do that I get the dreaded `System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission`. Looking at the source of DependencyInjection it suggests that ReflectionPermission is supposed to be granted for the injection stuff to work. But Medium Trust explicitly forbids ReflectionPermission. If I just skip the DependencyInjection stuff and try to use NHibernate as-is (which some people seem to suggest might just work) then I still get the same SecurityExceptions.

So you see the catch-22 that I am in. It sounds like I need to use DependencyInjection to get Medium Trust to work, yet DependencyInjection requires permission that Medium Trust doesn't provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, NH3 will **not** run in a default Medium Trust environment.

It can run in *customized* "medium trust" configurations that some shared hosting providers use. You need to test with the specific policy you will be targeting.

Comment: This seems like the case and is basically the conclusion I came to. Now I know there is a lot of old outdated documentation on NHibernate and Medium Trust out there (AllowTrustedCallers recompilations, etc...) including a lot that says "It just works!", but I can't find anything relatively new that talks about the simple example above. Any other VS2012 developer who develops in Medium Trust will run into the same problem. This *particularly* applies to NHibernate.DependencyInjection where it makes no mention of additional permissions required until you look at the source code.

Comment: So in short - I believe you, but is there anything out there that can back this up?

Comment: I think enough time has passed to accept this answer. Maybe if the situation changes, someone will post an update.